# ruamel.yaml dump of python classes containing properties seem to produce unexpected yaml formatting

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I am working on dumping python class data to YAML to be loaded at a later point in time.  I found that with ruamel.yaml (and PyYAML), that when I dump a class using a property to manage a class attribute the YAML output changes to what seems to be invalid YAML syntax.  I put together the code below to demonstrate the behavior

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

class MySampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, attribute1, attribute2):
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2

    @property
    def attribute1(self):
        return self.attribute1

    @attribute1.setter
    def attribute1(self, attribute1):
        self.__attribute1 = attribute1


sample1 = MySampleClass("ABCD", "123")
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.register_class(MySampleClass)
yaml.dump(sample1, sys.stdout)
```

When run this produces the output below. As you can see the decorated first property has unexpected formatting while the 2nd is what one would expect from YAML.

```
!MySampleClass
_MySampleClass__attribute1: ABCD
attribute2: '1234'
```

Is there a way to overcome this without writing custom constructors and representers for each class from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ruamel.yaml` doesn't handle properties/setters as "normal" attributes, that is why you get the funny output, which **is** valid YAML.

First of all though you should change your attribute1 property, as calling `print(sample1.attribute1)` will
get you into infinite recursion.

Then you can just make a single base class that has the appropriate `to_yaml` method that
can be used to dump all your classes:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

class ObjWithProperties(object):
    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        tag = getattr(cls, 'yaml_tag', '!' + cls.__name__)
        attribs = {}
        for x in dir(node):
            if x.startswith('_'):
                continue
            v = getattr(node, x)
            if callable(v):
                continue            
            attribs[x] = v
        return representer.represent_mapping(tag, attribs)


@yaml.register_class
class MySampleClass(ObjWithProperties):
    def __init__(self, attribute1, attribute2):
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2

    @property
    def attribute1(self):
        return self.__attribute1  # <<<< note the added double underscore to prevent recursion

    @attribute1.setter
    def attribute1(self, attribute1):
        self.__attribute1 = attribute1


sample1 = MySampleClass("ABCD", "123")
yaml.dump(sample1, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
!MySampleClass
attribute1: ABCD
attribute2: '123'
```